# When to bindTexture with manual mipmaps

Tags: webgl

When setting mipmap levels for a texture manually, which is the correct strategy for where to loop on each level?

*note: I'm assuming `gl.createTexture()` definitely falls outside the loop*

**OPTION A**

1. gl.bindTexture(bindTarget, texture);
2. gl.texParameteri();
3. For each mipmap level:

   - gl.texImage2D();

**OPTION B**

1. gl.bindTexture(bindTarget, texture);
2. For each mipmap level:

   - gl.texParameteri();
   - gl.texImage2D();

**OPTION C**

1. For each mipmap level:

   - gl.bindTexture(bindTarget, texture);
   - gl.texParameteri();
   - gl.texImage2D();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

texture parameters are for the entire texture not per mip level so option a.

It kind of seems like you could derive that given that those parameters help choose whether or not mips are used at all.

Comment: totally - the parameters don't change in any of the options, I just wasn't sure if they needed to be re-applied per gl.texImage2D() call or not - and the missing info was that it applies per-texture. Thanks!!